# Button doesn't react at clicking in RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a simple RecycleView component. Then create a new activity for that component. In one row I have a `TextView` and `Button`. What I want to do is to change something in object which was put into the excatly one row.

First I initialized the `Button`:

```
public class RecycleViewAllWashesActivity extends Activity {
    private Button isFavorite;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.row_recycleview);
        isFavorite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addToFav);
        isFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.w("myApp", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
                int id = v.getId();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The adapter of `RecycleView` looks like:

```
@Override
    public MyAdapter.WashLocationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_recycleview, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        WashLocationViewHolder viewHolder = new WashLocationViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    // Involves populating data into the item through holder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.WashLocationViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // Get the data model based on position
        WashLocation w = washLocations.get(position);
        String info = w.getWashName();

        // Set item views based on your views and data model
        TextView textView = viewHolder.info;
        textView.setText(info);

        Integer fav = w.getFav();
        Boolean favorite = fav == 1 ? true : false;
        Button addToFav = viewHolder.favorite;
        addToFav.setText(favorite == true ? "Usuń z ulubionych" : "Dodaj do ulubionych");
    }
```

**Questions:**

1. How to get the object which was put into one row?
2. When I clicked the `Button` (code above) it doesn't react, even breakpoint which was set there doesn't react? -> the thing in console which I see while clicking the button is:
   `04-17 13:11:00.137 7671-7671/com.example.micha.locationtest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN`

==============================
**Update:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private List<WashLocation> washLocations;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyAdapter(List<WashLocation> washLocations, Context context) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.washLocations = washLocations;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_recycleview, parent, false);
        return new ItemHolder(itemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        // Get the data model based on position
        WashLocation w = washLocations.get(position);
        String info = w.getWashName();

        // Set item views based on your views and data model
        TextView textView = holder.info;
        textView.setText(info);

        Integer fav = w.getFav();
        Boolean favorite = fav == 1 ? true : false;
        Button addToFav = holder.favorite;
        addToFav.setText(favorite == true ? "Usuń z ulubionych" : "Dodaj do ulubionych");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return washLocations.size();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        onItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
        return onItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);
    }

  /*  public void add(int location, String iName){
        itemsName.add(location, iName);
        notifyItemInserted(location);
    }

    public void remove(int location){
        if(location >= itemsName.size())
            return;

        itemsName.remove(location);
        notifyItemRemoved(location);
    }*/

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private MyAdapter parent;
        TextView textItemName;
        public TextView info;
        public Button favorite;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView, MyAdapter parent) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.parent = parent;
            info = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            favorite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToFav);
        }

        public void setItemName(CharSequence name) {
            textItemName.setText(name);
        }

        public CharSequence getItemName() {
            return textItemName.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The activity class:

```
final DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
washLocations = dataBaseHelper.getWashLocation();

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(washLocations, this);
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



 @Override
    public void onItemClick(MyAdapter.ItemHolder item, int position) {
        Log.d("myApp", "fdsgfds");
    }
```

Comment: theres no error code. Told you in second question

Comment: check out this simple example of recyclerView. I guess you misunderstood the implementation...http://android-er.blogspot.de/2015/07/simple-recyclerview-example.html

Comment: I didn't get you properly.. can u tell me what should happen when u click on isFavorite button?

Comment: you have implemented RecyclerView in totally wrong way, that´s why I provided the link. Look at the part how there is the ViewHolder implemented. I think you have to completely rebuild yoir RecyclerView implementation...

Comment: @Raghavendra it should print `Log.w("myApp", String.valueOf(v.getId()));`, but it nothing prints

Comment: can you show the row XML?

Comment: If there is clickable somewhere in xml it may be restricting the button click

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I have updated the code as you said and adapt to my condition and it still doesn't react at clicking..

Answer (score 0):

In Recycle review you must set an onClickListener for the views explicitly. 
It does not have any default methods to handle click events like the listview.

You need to set an Onclick listener for your button in your `WashLocationViewHolder`

You will receive a click event there. From the view holder, you can send the event back to your fragment or activity using an interface.

if you need further help regarding this, mention it in the comments. I will provide you some samples.

> How to get the object which was put into one row?

To do this you can set the object as a Tag using the `setTag(Object)` method in the layout or the button for which you will be providing a click listener. Then you can get the object using the `getTag()` method from the view.

Hope this helps.